# MUI v5 - Can't access MenuItem attribute through event.currentTarget after update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I previously was on v4 and had my Select and MenuItems setup like so:

```
const [select, setSelect] = useState('');
const [customName, setCustomName] = useState('');

const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSelect(event.target.value);
    setCustomName(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('name'));
  };

...

                <Select
                  label="Choose A Dataset"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={select}
                >
                  {tables &&
                    tables.map(
                      (table, index) =>
                          (
                          <MenuItem
                            key={table.name}
                            value={table.code}
                            name={table.name}
                          >
                            {table.name}
                          </MenuItem>
                        )
                    )}
                </Select>
```

and I could access the menuItem's name attribute through

```
event.currentTarget.getAttribute('name');
```

However, after the migration to v5, event.currentTarget returns null. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The `SelectInput` has this `onChange` definition:

```
onChange?: (event: SelectChangeEvent<T>, child: React.ReactNode) => void;
```

meaning that you can get the child clicked as the second param on your `handleChange`. Here you can access the name property with `child.props.name`.

However it's worth noting that `MenuItem` doesn't have a name prop and if you define it Typescript will highlight it as an error. To avoid this you could use the `event.target.value` to find the table with the matching `code` and get the name that way:

```
const name = tables.find((table) => table.code === event.target.value).name;
```